# Base constructor with params parameter called implicitly

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor

When inheriting a class that contains a constructor with parameters, the derived class must call this constructor. So the following code does not compile:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(string callBase)
    {
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    protected BaseClass(string callMe)
    {
    }
}
```

Because:

> The type 'BaseClass' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments

We must call the `base(string)` constructor:

```
public DerivedClass(string callBase)
    : base(callBase)
{
}
```

And all is well.

However, when the base class constructor contains a `params` parameter:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(string callBase)
    {
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    protected BaseClass(params string[] callMe)
    {
    }
}
```

Now we can agree that `BaseClass` still doesn't have a constructor that takes 0 arguments, yet the code above compiles.

In fact, the IL of the `DerivedClass` constructor shows:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0002:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.String
IL_0007:  call       instance void BaseClass::.ctor(string[])
```

It implicitly calls the base constructor with an empty array of the requested element type of the `params` parameter.

Also, when `DerivedClass` does *not* contain a constructor, the same IL is generated for the automatically generated parameterless constructor ("default constructor").

Why does the C# compiler do that, instead of generating the same warning as without the `params` modifier?

From the C# 6 specifications:

> **10.11.4 Default constructors**
>
> If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default instance constructor is automatically provided.
>   That default constructor simply invokes the parameterless constructor of the direct base class. If the class is abstract
>   then the declared accessibility for the default constructor is protected. Otherwise, the declared accessibility for the
>   default constructor is public. Thus, **the default constructor is always of the form**
>
> ```
> protected C(): base() {}
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> public C(): base() {}
> ```

Emphasis mine.

But then of course that's still true, because `base()` in turn gets compiled to `base(new string[])`.

Still, in the case of constructors, I'd rather get an error than an implicit call.

Comment: How is it different from regular invocation of method with `params`? If you pass no arguments - the same zero-length array is passed by compiler. Looks the same to me as implicit call to `base()` constructor.

Comment: @Evk true, but it's especially the error message in the non-params case, and the phrase _"If a class contains no instance constructor declarations, a default instance constructor is automatically provided.
That default constructor simply invokes the parameterless constructor of the direct base class"_ from the C# specs that triggered me to ask this. See edit.

Comment: But from C# compiler perspective there is constructor that takes 0 arguments in this case. You can do `new BaseClass()`, you can also do `public DerivedClass():base()`, passing no arguments. Don't see any contradiction with what you marked with bold.

Comment: @Evk also from the specs, 3.6 Signatures and overloading: _"The signature of an instance constructor
specifically does not include the `params` modifier that may be specified for the right-most parameter"_. So there _isn't_ a parameterless constructor. I do think the rules are "stacked" so to say, so the `params` rules get applied before applying the constructor rules and so a parameterless constructor implicitly gets generated before looking for applicable constructors, but I'd love if someone could explain that in a clear answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster [works even with constructors with default values](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/f:r/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUHgB2ACMAbMAYxgtIEMQQYARVAJzADdUATAYToYwAXDABC9VP3og8AbzwxFMImUrM2nHlIYAKFO2jVapUuJCoAlAqXzcSmAF88T/LhXkqNaWInaZuW3sCVgB7NAo0bh9zPx0CWlZadEZ9SCgAbQBdIxMAWUtrRUClFxdCEg9qAUYWdi4+aoAmYWjJJrlC5Qq1Ws0G6Ua9ZANYCmNTCSs7G07SvHLVT2rWv0aO6cVgsNQInhWmoZGc0nyYAF4YACIACTBLqftixVKgA==) (second example)

Comment: "Now we can agree that BaseClass still doesn't have a constructor that takes 0 arguments" - we can't, you know. I might be persuaded that it doesn't have a parameterless constructor but it definitely has a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Comment: @Chris yeah, so I think this question contains way too much fluff and that I might just be looking for an interpretation of the specs that shows me that a `params` or an optional parameter introduces an overload that technically takes zero arguments. :)

Comment: Note: `BaseClass` do not satisfy the `new()` type constraint. (ie: can't be used as type parameter `T` with `where T : new()` constraint).

Comment: Maybe @JaredPar can help on this one?